# NSUserDefault problem in iOS 4.2

Tags: ios, ios-4.2

I have prepared a "Settings.bundle" file that contains plist with properties.  However, after I compile and load the app, I can't find the those properties in [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults].  After I go to the settings and modify the properties there, all the modified properties can be found in [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] (the unmodified ones are still missing).  Is this a known problem in iOS 4.2?  I tried the same program in iOS 3.2 and it was ok.

Comment: See the answer from user pwc in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675877/nsuserdefaults-not-working-right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a library that duplicates the settings from setting.bundle inside the app, during that I discovered that the defaults in setting.bundle are not registered unless the user goes to the app's settings in the settings app. Here's the function I wrote that goes though the all the plists in the settings.bundle and registers the user defaults: http://bitbucket.org/keegan3d/inappsettings/src/2053acd0524e/InAppSettings/InAppSettingsReader.m

I'm not sure why it's working in iOS 3.2 for you but it might be that the settings are registered from a previous build.

Comment: Thanks.  It works in the simulator, but doesn't work for real device.  Do you know why?

Comment: Hmm not sure, try deleting the app from your phone before building and installing again. Maybe there are lingering preferences on the device.