# NSUserDefaults not working right

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

Having some trouble with `NSUserDefaults` here.

Here's how I'm creating it:

```
NSString *theCity = @"Test City";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:theCity forKey:@"SavedCity"];
```

Here's how I'm trying to retrieve it:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SavedCity"])  
    {
         NSLog(@"Key exists! %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SavedCity"]);
    }
    else {
         NSLog(@"No city saved!");
    }
```

The problem I have is that even if there IS a key for "SavedCity" (I check the pref file in the Simulator directory), it always displays "No city saved".  Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen in a vanilla application?  Like, is this happening in any other place than your app?

Comment: @Dave No this is the only time this has happened before in this app.

Comment: Terminate the application by holding the mouse of the application icon and typing "quit" instead of using the stop button of xcode.This way the user defaults gets saved properly to the database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two things you could try.

1) Try synchronizing the user defaults after settings the string. `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]`

2) Try retrieving the string using `-stringForKey:`

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This wasn't the problem, but instead I finally tracked it down to the original string being null sometimes.  Thanks again.

Comment: Please don't suggest sprinkling in -synchronize calls to fix NSUserDefaults issues. It's pretty slow, blocks every thread touching the defaults system, and is *almost never* useful, particularly on iOS. The main use explicit synchronization has is when dealing with other defaults domains (global preferences, another app's preferences, etc...).

Answer (score 8):

I ran into a similar problem myself recently.  Here's what fixed it for me.

From the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW21):

> It is recommended that you register any default preference values programmatically at launch time in addition to including them in your settings bundle property lists. For newly installed applications, default preference values from the application’s settings bundle are not set until the Settings application runs. This means that if the user runs your application before running Settings, the default values specified in your settings bundle will not be available. Setting such values programmatically at launch time ensures that your application always has appropriate values. To register default values programmatically, use the `registerDefaults:` method of the `NSUserDefaults` class.

Answer (score 0):

What you should add is:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SavedCity"] != nil)
```

Because you want to check if you've saved something.

Comment: While less explicit, the author's current code does the same thing.