# NSUserDefaults data not Working

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I have implemented a `UITableView` in VC1 to display firstName and LastName of the user,and a edit Button at the top of the `UITableView`. When the user presses the button it navigates through navigation controller to VC2.

In  VC2 the user can update the `firstName` and `LastName` Fields. I am saving the details Using `NSUserDefaults` as

```
NSUserDefaults*first=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[first setValue:textField1.text forKey:@"firstname"];
```

While I go back to VC1 and try to display the updated data its not working why is it so...?

```
NSUserDefaults*first=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
cell.detailTextLabel.text=[first valueForKey:@"firstname"];
```

How can I do it using `NSUserDefaults`.?

Comment: I think Google could help you

Comment: Refer this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074483/save-string-to-the-nsuserdefaults

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSUserDefaults not working right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675877/nsuserdefaults-not-working-right)

Comment: have you tried any of the below ans?

Comment: Yes But Not working

Comment: Are you getting or fetching NSUserDefaults value in viewDidLoad() ?

Comment: Nope its showing null in VC1 but in VC2 its saving

Comment: Try to get NSUserDefaults value in viewWillAppear() of VC1. When you press back button then viewWillAppear() called. Which help you to fetch New data of NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSUserDefault` is working fine, you just need to reload your table on `viewWillApear` event.

```
//In VC1

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [_yourTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: is this answer helpful to u? If yes please accept and up vote so this can be helpful to other.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use set**Object**:forKey

```
NSUserDefaults*first=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[first setObject:textField1.text forKey:@"firstname"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put breakpoint, after entering new "firstName" && "lastName".
And in console print

```
po [first objectForKey:@"firstName"]
```

if its your value, then you should dig deeper in updating/refreshing data in first VC. Like [MyTable reloadData] or some.

Answer (score -1):

Try below line of code

```
NSUserDefaults *first=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[first setValue:textField1.text forKey:@"firstname"];
[first synchronize]; // have to write this line of code.


NSUserDefaults *first=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

cell.detailTextLabel.text=[first valueForKey:@"firstname"];
```

Comment: please read question carefully then understand real problem after that answer a question.